Raspberry Pi CM4. Is it possible fstrim deleted/corrupted needed files?
I have a problem. On my device (Raspberry Pi CM4) my programm uses /var/opt directory (files created/downloaded manually). After some hard reset my program cant see couple of files, I go into the log and see these rows:
Aug 22 12:23:26  systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab...
Aug 22 12:23:26 fstrim[1180]: /: 1.7 GiB (1784496128 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p2
Aug 22 12:23:26 fstrim[1180]: /boot: 204.5 MiB (214468608 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p1
Aug 22 12:23:26 systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Succeeded.
Aug 22 12:23:26 systemd[1]: Finished Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab.

After these rows, in this time of boot my program broken (needed file was not found).
Is it possible that fstrim deleted my files? I dont see any other reasons from logs.
I did see these rows earlier (another date):
Aug 19 00:06:01 systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab...
Aug 19 00:06:01 fstrim[8312]: /: 389.6 MiB (408547328 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p2
Aug 19 00:06:01 fstrim[8312]: /boot: 204.5 MiB (214468608 bytes) trimmed on /dev/mmcblk0p1
Aug 19 00:06:01 systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Succeeded.
Aug 19 00:06:01 systemd[1]: Finished Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab.

But after them all was OK.
Aug 19 389MB, Aug 22 1.7GB o_O
I used mmc-utils for cheking of eMMC health:
=============================================
  Extended CSD rev 1.8 (MMC 5.1)
=============================================

Card Supported Command sets [S_CMD_SET: 0x01]
HPI Features [HPI_FEATURE: 0x01]: implementation based on CMD13
Background operations support [BKOPS_SUPPORT: 0x01]
Max Packet Read Cmd [MAX_PACKED_READS: 0x3f]
Max Packet Write Cmd [MAX_PACKED_WRITES: 0x3f]
Data TAG support [DATA_TAG_SUPPORT: 0x01]
Data TAG Unit Size [TAG_UNIT_SIZE: 0x02]
Tag Resources Size [TAG_RES_SIZE: 0x00]
Context Management Capabilities [CONTEXT_CAPABILITIES: 0x05]
Large Unit Size [LARGE_UNIT_SIZE_M1: 0x07]
Extended partition attribute support [EXT_SUPPORT: 0x03]
Generic CMD6 Timer [GENERIC_CMD6_TIME: 0x0a]
Power off notification [POWER_OFF_LONG_TIME: 0x3c]
Cache Size [CACHE_SIZE] is 65536 KiB
Background operations status [BKOPS_STATUS: 0x00]
1st Initialisation Time after programmed sector [INI_TIMEOUT_AP: 0x1e]
Power class for 52MHz, DDR at 3.6V [PWR_CL_DDR_52_360: 0x00]
Power class for 52MHz, DDR at 1.95V [PWR_CL_DDR_52_195: 0x00]
Power class for 200MHz at 3.6V [PWR_CL_200_360: 0x00]
Power class for 200MHz, at 1.95V [PWR_CL_200_195: 0x00]
Minimum Performance for 8bit at 52MHz in DDR mode:
 [MIN_PERF_DDR_W_8_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_DDR_R_8_52: 0x00]
TRIM Multiplier [TRIM_MULT: 0x02]
Secure Feature support [SEC_FEATURE_SUPPORT: 0x55]
Boot Information [BOOT_INFO: 0x07]
 Device supports alternative boot method
 Device supports dual data rate during boot
 Device supports high speed timing during boot
Boot partition size [BOOT_SIZE_MULTI: 0x20]
Access size [ACC_SIZE: 0x07]
High-capacity erase unit size [HC_ERASE_GRP_SIZE: 0x01]
 i.e. 512 KiB
High-capacity erase timeout [ERASE_TIMEOUT_MULT: 0x01]
Reliable write sector count [REL_WR_SEC_C: 0x01]
High-capacity W protect group size [HC_WP_GRP_SIZE: 0x10]
 i.e. 8192 KiB
Sleep current (VCC) [S_C_VCC: 0x07]
Sleep current (VCCQ) [S_C_VCCQ: 0x07]
Sleep/awake timeout [S_A_TIMEOUT: 0x11]
Sector Count [SEC_COUNT: 0x00e90000]
 Device is block-addressed
Minimum Write Performance for 8bit:
 [MIN_PERF_W_8_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_R_8_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_W_8_26_4_52: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_R_8_26_4_52: 0x00]
Minimum Write Performance for 4bit:
 [MIN_PERF_W_4_26: 0x00]
 [MIN_PERF_R_4_26: 0x00]
Power classes registers:
 [PWR_CL_26_360: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_52_360: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_26_195: 0x00]
 [PWR_CL_52_195: 0x00]
Partition switching timing [PARTITION_SWITCH_TIME: 0x02]
Out-of-interrupt busy timing [OUT_OF_INTERRUPT_TIME: 0x0a]
I/O Driver Strength [DRIVER_STRENGTH: 0x1f]
Card Type [CARD_TYPE: 0x57]
 HS200 Single Data Rate eMMC @200MHz 1.8VI/O
 HS Dual Data Rate eMMC @52MHz 1.8V or 3VI/O
 HS eMMC @52MHz - at rated device voltage(s)
 HS eMMC @26MHz - at rated device voltage(s)
CSD structure version [CSD_STRUCTURE: 0x02]
Command set [CMD_SET: 0x00]
Command set revision [CMD_SET_REV: 0x00]
Power class [POWER_CLASS: 0x00]
High-speed interface timing [HS_TIMING: 0x01]
Erased memory content [ERASED_MEM_CONT: 0x00]
Boot configuration bytes [PARTITION_CONFIG: 0x00]
 Not boot enable
 No access to boot partition
Boot config protection [BOOT_CONFIG_PROT: 0x00]
Boot bus Conditions [BOOT_BUS_CONDITIONS: 0x00]
High-density erase group definition [ERASE_GROUP_DEF: 0x01]
Boot write protection status registers [BOOT_WP_STATUS]: 0x00
Boot Area Write protection [BOOT_WP]: 0x00
 Power ro locking: possible
 Permanent ro locking: possible
 ro lock status: not locked
User area write protection register [USER_WP]: 0x00
FW configuration [FW_CONFIG]: 0x00
RPMB Size [RPMB_SIZE_MULT]: 0x04
Write reliability setting register [WR_REL_SET]: 0x1f
 user area: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 1: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 2: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 3: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
 partition 4: the device protects existing data if a power failure occurs during a write operation
Write reliability parameter register [WR_REL_PARAM]: 0x14
 Device supports the enhanced def. of reliable write
Enable background operations handshake [BKOPS_EN]: 0x00
H/W reset function [RST_N_FUNCTION]: 0x00
HPI management [HPI_MGMT]: 0x01
Partitioning Support [PARTITIONING_SUPPORT]: 0x07
 Device support partitioning feature
 Device can have enhanced tech.
Max Enhanced Area Size [MAX_ENH_SIZE_MULT]: 0x0001d2
 i.e. 3817472 KiB
Partitions attribute [PARTITIONS_ATTRIBUTE]: 0x00
Partitioning Setting [PARTITION_SETTING_COMPLETED]: 0x00
 Device partition setting NOT complete
General Purpose Partition Size
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_4]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_3]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_2]: 0x000000
 [GP_SIZE_MULT_1]: 0x000000
Enhanced User Data Area Size [ENH_SIZE_MULT]: 0x000000
 i.e. 0 KiB
Enhanced User Data Start Address [ENH_START_ADDR]: 0x00000000
 i.e. 0 bytes offset
Bad Block Management mode [SEC_BAD_BLK_MGMNT]: 0x00
Periodic Wake-up [PERIODIC_WAKEUP]: 0x00
Program CID/CSD in DDR mode support [PROGRAM_CID_CSD_DDR_SUPPORT]: 0x01
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[127]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[126]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[125]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[124]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[123]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[122]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[121]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[120]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[119]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[118]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[117]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[116]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[115]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[114]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[113]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[112]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[111]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[110]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[109]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[108]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[107]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[106]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[105]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[104]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[103]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[102]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[101]]: 0x05
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[100]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[99]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[98]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[97]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[96]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[95]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[94]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[93]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[92]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[91]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[90]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[89]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[88]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[87]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[86]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[85]]: 0x01
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[84]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[83]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[82]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[81]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[80]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[79]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[78]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[77]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[76]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[75]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[74]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[73]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[72]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[71]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[70]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[69]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[68]]: 0xc8
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[67]]: 0xc8
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[66]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[65]]: 0x00
Vendor Specific Fields [VENDOR_SPECIFIC_FIELD[64]]: 0x0f
Native sector size [NATIVE_SECTOR_SIZE]: 0x00
Sector size emulation [USE_NATIVE_SECTOR]: 0x00
Sector size [DATA_SECTOR_SIZE]: 0x00
1st initialization after disabling sector size emulation [INI_TIMEOUT_EMU]: 0x00
Class 6 commands control [CLASS_6_CTRL]: 0x00
Number of addressed group to be Released[DYNCAP_NEEDED]: 0x00
Exception events control [EXCEPTION_EVENTS_CTRL]: 0x0000
Exception events status[EXCEPTION_EVENTS_STATUS]: 0x0000
Extended Partitions Attribute [EXT_PARTITIONS_ATTRIBUTE]: 0x0000
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[51]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[50]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[49]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[48]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[47]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[46]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[45]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[44]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[43]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[42]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[41]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[40]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[39]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[38]]: 0x00
Context configuration [CONTEXT_CONF[37]]: 0x00
Packed command status [PACKED_COMMAND_STATUS]: 0x00
Packed command failure index [PACKED_FAILURE_INDEX]: 0x00
Power Off Notification [POWER_OFF_NOTIFICATION]: 0x01
Control to turn the Cache ON/OFF [CACHE_CTRL]: 0x01
eMMC Firmware Version: 
eMMC Life Time Estimation A [EXT_CSD_DEVICE_LIFE_TIME_EST_TYP_A]: 0x01
eMMC Life Time Estimation B [EXT_CSD_DEVICE_LIFE_TIME_EST_TYP_B]: 0x01
eMMC Pre EOL information [EXT_CSD_PRE_EOL_INFO]: 0x01
Command Queue Support [CMDQ_SUPPORT]: 0x01
Command Queue Depth [CMDQ_DEPTH]: 16
Command Enabled [CMDQ_MODE_EN]: 0x00

If it was not fstrim, how was files corrupted, what do I need check?
Sorry for my not ideal english

"After some hard reset my program cant see couple of files" - the files aren't listed in the directory, or they are empty, or you have a permissions problem opening them, or...? Please be precise. What did you do? What happened? Did you get any error messages?

Not sure how to answer specifically. In general, reported values by fstrim are not very interesting. As long as the amount of data trimmed is not larger than free space, you should be fine. Corruption is possible if there is a bug (in filesystem, kernel, or hardware).
